# Updating one object with another

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I update an `object` with another `object`?

for example

```
master = { name: "John", email: "j@j.com" }

child = { phone: "888-333-3999" }
```

How can I  update `master` with `child`?

Output of `master` need to be

```
{ name: "John", email: "j@j.com", phone: "888-333-3999" }
```

Also, this is a `node.js JavaScript`, I don't want to use `jQuery`.

Comment: no its for node.js javascript

Comment: Here's the answer then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22948578/1208233

Comment: Nothing in your question involved JSON in any way. You're dealing with JavaScript objects.

Comment: Oh please, stop using the phrase **JSON object**. JSON is a **string**.

Comment: Merge properties of two JavaScript objects
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, you just need to iterate over one object and copy its properties/values into the other object:

```
for (key in child) master[key] = child[key];
```